# What is this date format called?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

What is this date format called: **1YYMMDD**

Example: 06/28/1959 outputs as 1590628
Example: 06/28/2019 outputs as 1190628

There is always a stinking 1 in front of it, no matter what.

Comment: It's called my worst nightmare.

Comment: It's called a [Century Marker](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1019641). `0` is for 1900's, `1` is for 2000's

Comment: Mine too Jacob but with Tom giving me the name of it, it's about to no longer be :)

Comment: It's your date in a YYYYMMDD format (as a number) - 19000000.  Which is just awful, but there you go.  20190628 - 19000000 = 1190628.

Comment: I'm good now, that "Century Marker" got me looking where i needed to be, to resolve my date formatting issue. I should have spent the 30 minutes it took to do this years ago.

Comment: Cox, just out of curiosity where are you encountering this format? In an input file, etc..? Good think Tom knew the proper terminology.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomNash already mentioned in his comment the `1` seems to be a [century marker](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1019641).

So your date format is `CYYMMDD` where C could be

- 0 : for 19xx
- 1 : for 20xx

This kind of format is **not** part of [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)!

It looks to be a little bit like an IBM special and maybe AS/400 specific solution for the [year-2000-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem).

My personal recommendation is to convert such date formats always to ISO 8601 via an    intermediate layer before processing them.

Last but not least please remember to set software that use such outdated formats onto a list, because a solution like the century marker has only moved the year-2000-problem 100 years to the future - so the childs of our grandchilds will have the same problem again ...